# How do I create an account with Wizards of the Coast if I have a very old DCI number without activation code?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

During Battle for Zendikar prerelease yesterday I played my first "real cards" MTG tournament since GP Vienna around 2003-ish. Now I learned that there is now a DCI website where you can look up your tournament results, Planeswalker points, etc. Apparently, it is this one: https://accounts.wizards.com

Now I am wondering how to actually create an account there using my existing (8-digit) DCI number from way back. Using **Create Account** won't do, as it seems to create a new, unchangeable, DCI number. Using **Activate DCI number** functionality does not do what I want, since my number is from long before activation codes were a thing.

I have considered contacting support, but based on previous interactions I was hoping that there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

The website http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2301/=1

Actually answers this question, but not quite obvious.

It says numbers shorter than 10 digits have been converted and that you can receive your DCI number either at a local WPN store (where you have to ask) or via the contact form.

Comment: I tried the contact form just some hours ago with my old DCI number and they just have sent me an activation code. So, I can confirm that using it works.

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](http://magic.wizards.com/en/myaccounts/FAQ) indicates that you can merge multiple DCI numbers into one account. This may be a way for you to get what you want, by first making a new account, and then merging in your old DCI number. The fine print, however, suggests that this will only work for previously activated DCI numbers, so you may again be out of luck there and need to contact customer support.

Comment: Tried, but the "merging" functionality actually merges accounts, not DCI numbers. You have to log into both accounts first (which I cannot).

Answer (score 0):

You may already have an account, and just need to reset your password. I have an 8-digit DCI number and resetting my password was how I gained access to the account. You don't need to merge unless you have multiple DCI numbers.